# Prevent undesired conversion in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, explicit-constructor

According to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), `explicit`:

> Specifies constructors and conversion operators (since C++11) that
>   don't allow implicit conversions or copy-initialization.

Thus, are these two techniques identical?

```
struct Z {
        // ...
        Z(long long);     // can initialize with a long long
        Z(long) = delete; // but not anything smaller
};

struct Z {
        // ...
        explicit Z(long long);     // can initialize ONLY with a long long
};
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They're not identical.

```
Z z = 1LL;
```

The above works with the non-explicit version, but not with the explicit version.

Declaring constructor of `Z` explicit doesn't prevent conversion of the constructor argument from another type. It prevents the conversion from the argument to `Z` without calling the constructor explicitly.

Below is an example of explicit constructor call.

```
Z z = Z(1LL);
```

Comment: Note, that calls the explicit constructor, and also the copy/move constructor. `Z z(1LL);` would call only the explicit constructor.

Answer (score 28):

No, they're not the same. `explicit` disallows implicit conversions to that type if that constructor is selected - implicit conversions in arguments don't matter. `delete` disallows any construction if that constructor is selected, and can be used to disallow implicit *argument* conversion.

So for instance:

```
struct X {
    explicit X(int ) { }
};

void foo(X ) { }

foo(4);      // error, because X's constructor is explicit
foo(X{3});   // ok
foo(X{'3'}); // ok, this conversion is fine
```

That is separate from `delete`ing a constructor:

```
struct Y {
    Y(int ) { }
    Y(char ) = delete;
};

void bar(Y ) { }

bar(4);      // ok, implicit conversion to Y since this constructor isn't explicit
bar('4');    // error, this constructor is deleted
bar(Y{'4'}); // error, doesn't matter that we're explicit
```

The two techniques are also orthogonal. If you want a type to not be implicitly-convertible *and* only constructible from exactly an `int`, you can do both:

```
struct W {
    explicit W(int ) { }

    template <class T>
    W(T ) = delete;
};

void quux(W );

quux(4);      // error, constructor is explicit
quux('4');    // error, constructor is deleted
quux(4L);     // error, constructor is deleted
quux(W{'4'}); // error, constructor is deleted
quux(W{5});   // ok
```

Comment: blech, unnecessary use of uniform init. Use direct init plix.

Comment: @Puppy You downvoted me because I used braces? Seriously?

Comment: Actually, brace initializers are also encouraged by Stroustrup (section 6.3.5, "The C++ Programming Language - 4th ed.", B.S., 2013).

Comment: @Puppy: They call it uniform init because it *always works* and is *never wrong*.  Why would you possibly want to avoid that?

Answer (score 6):

`explicit` blocks implicit conversion *to your type*.

Your `=delete` technique blocks implicit conversion from `long` to `long long`.

These are almost unrelated.

There are 4 cases that illustrate the difference:

```
Z z = 1L;
Z z = 1LL;
```

is an implicit conversion from `long` and `long long` to `Z`.

```
Z z = Z(1L);
Z z = Z(1LL);
```

is an explicit conversion from `long` and `long long` to `Z`.

`explicit Z(long long)` blocks:

```
Z z = 1L;
Z z = 1LL;
```

while `Z(long)=delete` blocks:

```
Z z = 1L;
Z z = Z(1L);
```

`explicit Z(long long)` allows `Z z = Z(1L)` because the conversion from `long` to `long long` is implicit, but unrelated to the explicit conversion to `Z` that happens afterwards.

Note that a mixture of `explicit` and `=delete` leaves only `Z z=Z(1LL)` as valid among your 4 versions.

(the above presumes a valid copy or move ctor; if not, replace `Z z=Z(...)` with `Z z(...)` and the same conclusions result).

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Zb {
        Zb(long long)
        {};     // can initialize with a long long
        Zb(long) = delete; // but not anything smaller
    };

struct Za {
        // ...
        explicit Za(long long)
        {};     // can initialize ONLY with a long long
    };

int main()
{
    Za((long long)10);  // works
    Za((long)10);       // works    

    Zb((long long)10);  // works
    Zb((long)10);       // does not work

    return 0;
}
```

Your example requires explicit deleting.

Live: http://cpp.sh/4sqb

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

From the standard working draft `n4296`:

> `12.3.1 - [class.conv.ctor]:`
>   <sup>1</sup>  A constructor declared *without* the function-specifier explicit specifies a conversion from the types of its
>   parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.
>
> <sup>2</sup> An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so only where the
>   direct-initialization syntax (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are explicitly used. A default constructor
>   may be an explicit constructor; such a constructor will be used to perform default-initialization or valueinitialization
>   (8.5).

Followed by an example of each one respectively:

```
struct X {
    X(int);
    X(const char*, int =0);
    X(int, int);
};

void f(X arg) {
    X a = 1;        // a = X(1)
    X b = "Jessie"; // b = X("Jessie",0)
    a = 2;          // a = X(2)
    f(3);           // f(X(3))
    f({1, 2});      // f(X(1,2))
}
```

With explicit constructor:

```
struct Z {
    explicit Z();
    explicit Z(int);
    explicit Z(int, int);
};

Z a;                      // OK: default-initialization performed
Z a1 = 1;                 // error: no implicit conversion
Z a3 = Z(1);              // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z a2(1);                  // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z* p = new Z(1);          // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z a4 = (Z)1;              // OK: explicit cast used
Z a5 = static_cast<Z>(1); // OK: explicit cast used
Z a6 = { 3, 4 };          // error: no implicit conversion
```